# JavaScript override method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to override a javascript method with my own version.

Let me explain, you have the below code(Part of Code)

```
Reports_Edit_Js("Reports_Edit1_Js",{},{

    relatedModulesMapping  : false,
    step1Container : false,
    secondaryModulesContainer : false,

    init : function() {
        this.initialize();
    },
    /**
     * Function to get the container which holds all the reports step1 elements
     * @return jQuery object
     */
    getContainer : function() {
        return this.step1Container;
    },


    DateToYMD : function (date) {
        var year, month, day;
        year = String(date.getFullYear());
        month = String(date.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = String(date.getDate());
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }
}
```

Now the question is, if there is any way to override the method DateToYMD from Reports_Edit1_Js with a custom method without change original file or define all methods.

i tried the following code but not working

```
Reports_Edit_Js("Reports_Edit1_Js").prototype.DateToYMD = function(date){
        var year, month, day;
        year = String(date.getFullYear());
        month = String(date.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = String(date.getDate());
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        return year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
};
```

[Complete code is here](http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/layouts/v7/modules/Reports/resources/Edit1.js) also [Reports_Edit_Js](http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/layouts/v7/modules/Reports/resources/Edit.js)

Comment: is this your complete code?

Comment: Complete code is here  [link](http://code.vtiger.com/vtiger/vtigercrm/blob/master/layouts/v7/modules/Reports/resources/Edit1.js)

Comment: i tried with your first code and it is giving me an error

Comment: part of code is giving an error

Comment: @Hamid it's not clear what the code you posted is. `Reports_Edit_Js` is not a function definition. Your code is *calling* the function `Reports_Edit_Js`. Is this using a framework or some sort?  Or are you missing a closing `)`?

Comment: Reports_Edit_Js  is a function that load Reports_Edit1_Js, Complete code added

Comment: @Hamid the function `DateToYMD` that you want to override is on the object you are passing in to `Reports_Edit_Js` not on `Reports_Edit_Js` itself.

Comment: Is this possible and how? Do you have a sample code for testing?